# Jupyter notebook running in Voila, detecting kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, voila

Running Jupyter Notebooks using Voila, Python 3.9, on Windows 10...

I was wondering if, in the notebook code itself, there is a way to find out whether the kernel is still alive and kicking.